# Laptop automatically suspend when I connect any USB device

Tags: 16.04

[Power Setting of my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvbI3.png) I am using Ubuntu 16.04, suddenly my laptop suspend on battery when I connect any USB device(Mouse,Pendrive,Mobile,etc.) except cooling-pad, On power cable laptop working fine.

Comment: Anything of interest in the logs?

Comment: Where I can check it out?

Comment: Search applications for log

Comment: I have triple boot system, In windows 7 and Kali laptop works absolutely fine! Only in Ubuntu I have this problem from today's morning.

Comment: And you've tested it this morning in your other operating systems? What does it say in the logs?

Comment: When I connect USB it says :  
 **Sep 16 21:13:23 jay-Aspire-4736 NetworkManager[744]: <info>  [1474040603.0314] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)**

Comment: Is the battery very low?

Comment: Nope, It's 91% currently

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a picture of your power settings?

Comment: Thanks bro... after some observation of log, I found TLP is creating problem so I uninstalled it and the issue is solve...

Comment: Please feel free to answer to your own question (that's encouraged here) and include the steps you used to solve it so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several observations of log, I found TLP is creating problem so I uninstalled it and the issue is solve...